# Should namespace names be in plural form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, namespaces

Routing question. Are there any instances when namespace names can be pluralized?

Or are all namespaces supposed to be in singular form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both have their uses. You have an example of each in the ubiquitous `System.Windows.Forms`.

Edit: I just saw that the question is related to Ruby. However, namespace naming is pretty language-agnostic, so I think my answer still applies.